# Writing a recursive function in C# to create a string from characters

Tags: c#, string, recursion, char

Currently, I have something like the following:

```
public char functName(int n)
{
    some functionality....
    if(condition1)
        return convertFuncToChar(variable) + functName(modifiedNumber);
    else
        return convertFuncToChar(variable);
}
```

however, I realize that doesn't give me a string (and the syntax shows that there's an error).

I know that for c++, I would most likely use char* to initialize the function, but this is C#.

I don't think it works if I initialize with String either.

Comment: `public string functName(int n)`?

Comment: It would help a lot if you you show the *actual* code, or a least enough for us to understand what this function does.

Comment: You *probably* don't want this method to be recursive to begin with.  It certainly doesn't seem like a good fit here.  What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: Of course it doesn't give you a string, your return type is `char`.

Comment: From what I gather you are looking for one of 2 things: `new string(char[])` or the `StringBuilder`, but I agree with the other comments, more code would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, you can take advantage of two things:
1) all basic types implement .ToString(), which creates a string for you
2) string implements operator+()

The following is an example of a recursive function that will recursively concatenate characters to create a string. The output is the number in reverse as a string.

```
static string funcName(int n)
{
    if (n<10)
        return (n%10).ToString();
    return (n%10).ToString() + funcName(n/10);
}
```

Of course, it would be more efficient to write this non-recursively.

Comment: ToString is a good recommendation. thanks. 
I am assuming by non-recursive, you are suggesting a standard function used in a loop to carry out what I need?. I can try that as well. maybe it can reduce the total processed line count.

Comment: Exactly, typically using a stack and/or while loop.  In the above example:
`    static string funcName2(int n)
    {  
        string s = "";  
        while (n>0)  
        {  
            s += (n%10).ToString();  
            n/=10;  
        }  
        return s;  
    }